# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure

Tags: sql, vb6, sql-server-2000

I need your help on this guys!!!!

During the upload of the files to a database, this error occurs. 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure

Now here's what I did so far based on the articles which I've been reading.
1. I restarted the servers that are involved.
2. I've added a new DNS connection to pattern to what they are using to connect to the database.

But all of these failed. I don't know what to do because this is now critical and it's been a week now.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one, it work for me......

```
Set Cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Cnn.Open "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=" & txtServer & ";Database=" & cmbDatabase.Text & ";MARS Connection=True;DataTypeCompatibility=80;UID=" & txtUser & ";PWD=" & txtPassword & ";"
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried solutions proposed here:

--[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication Link Failure
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/b7a4c6f2-0d1b-44ba-bb55-0e7848d64198/

and here:

--Error message when an application connects to SQL Server on a server that is running Windows Server 2003: "General Network error," "Communication link failure," or "A transport-level error"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942861

Maybe you should look into logs, on whether there are no problems with SQL Server's service.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive the following error messages in one form or another in a job or SSIS package:

> "Communication link failure", "TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available."

A very likely cause is the code being run was created in BIDS which uses Visual Studio 2008 as its SDK base and the package or job was moved to a SQL Server 2012 server which is Visual Studio 2012 based.

You cannot simply go into the package and change a connections server name in this case. BIDS (aka VS 2008) uses `SQL Server connection Provider=SQLNCLI10.1`. TFS (aka VS 2012) uses `SQL Server connection Provider=SQLNCLI11.1`. If you are refactoring a package that was originally created in VS 2008 please do so in VS 2012 and drop and recreate the connections using the 2012 provider, it is backward compatible.The 2008 provider is not forward compatible. If you are creating a new package please do so in VS 2012. This, most often, will solve the problem.